# Terrible performance degradation in postgreSQL when i created too many partitions

Tags: performance, postgresql

I don't understand why occur performance degradation in postgreSQL when i created too many partitions for a table.

- 100 ->                           0.05 sec
- 200 ->                           0.07 sec
- 400 ->                           0.16 sec
- 600 ->                           0.24 sec
- 800 ->                           0.29 sec
- 1,000  ->                        0.37 sec
- 1,500  ->                        0.62 sec
- 2,000  ->                        0.82 sec
- 4,000  ->                        1.86 sec
- 10,000 ->                        7.62 sec

Below is the test query and the result of explain.

```
select count(*) from test_sql_stat_daily
where partition_key=1000000099;

Aggregate  (cost=20000000011.88..20000000011.89 rows=1 width=0)"
  Output: count(*)"
  ->  Append  (cost=10000000000.00..20000000011.88 rows=2 width=0)"
        ->  Seq Scan on test_sql_stat_daily  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000000.00 rows=1 width=0)"
              Filter: (test_sql_stat_daily.partition_key = 1000000099)"
        ->  Seq Scan on test_sql_stat_daily_p0000000099 test_sql_stat_daily  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000011.88 rows=1 width=0)"
              Filter: (test_sql_stat_daily.partition_key = 1000000099)"
```

I want to overcome this situation. 
And there is no effect for this situation.

1. increase the size of shared buffer
2. create index for primary key constraint (and create index) for CHECK constraint column
3. set constraint_exclusion = on

Comment: I upvoted! I know of the performance degradation when having way too much partitions, but never bothered testing myself. I tend to believe that posted number show mostly planning time (judging by the `rows=1` estimates). And it is a nice thing to scare young DBAs: “Hey, haivng 10k partitions on an empty table will make your queries run not less then 7 seconds!” :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about creating an insane number of partitions.

Answer (score 9):

The [documented approach](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-partitioning.html) is "Don't do that."

> All constraints on all partitions of the master table are examined
>   during constraint exclusion, so large numbers of partitions are likely
>   to increase query planning time considerably. Partitioning using these
>   techniques will work well with up to perhaps a hundred partitions;
>   **don't try to use many thousands of partitions**.

Emphasis added.

I'd try to get the number of partitions down to 1000 if I were you.

Comment: It also seems to be true for declarative partitioning

Comment: Here some interesting graphs comparing a table with a [low number](https://mageddo.github.io/java-examples/sql-data-partitioning/docs/report-02/report/content/pages/OverTime.html) of partitions and other [with a high one](https://mageddo.github.io/java-examples/sql-data-partitioning/docs/report-04/report/content/pages/OverTime.html)

Comment: As a workaround you can select/insert directly from partition at the critical points of your code where you need high performance, it's not a big deal but you can take advantage of constraint and indexes management out of the box